# Fade in fade out using dynamic range input speed and Repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

am Trying to control the speed and repeat of my fade in fade out div using range buttons but i am confused how to do this .please help me if you have any idea.Here is my code.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var faderIndex = 0,
    faders = $('.fadey');
    function nextFade() {
        $(faders[faderIndex]).fadeOut(2000, function() {
            faderIndex++;
            if (faderIndex >= faders.length)
                faderIndex = 0;
            $(faders[faderIndex]).fadeIn(3000, nextFade);
        });
    }
    nextFade();
});
</script>
<body id="d1" style="text-align:center" >
    <div class="fadey"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: @user1537158 for this code i am trying to give fade in speed using range input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Button Method ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KYaAj/1/))**

First we'll make some buttons in your HTML

```
<button id="fast">Fast</button>
<button id="normal">Normal</button>
<button id="slow">Slow</button>
<div id="fadey1" class="fadey"></div>
<div id="fadey2" class="fadey"></div>
```

Next, we'll bind click handlers on the buttons to change some variables that will replace the static millisecond values you are using in your function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var faderIndex = 0,
        faderOutSpeed = 2000,
        faderInSpeed = 3000,
        faders = $('.fadey');

    $('button#fast').click(function () {
        faderOutSpeed = 200;
        faderInSpeed = 300;
    });

    $('button#normal').click(function () {
        faderOutSpeed = 600;
        faderInSpeed = 900;
    });

    $('button#slow').click(function () {
        faderOutSpeed = 2000;
        faderInSpeed = 3000;
    });

    function nextFade() {
        $(faders[faderIndex]).fadeOut(faderInSpeed, function () {
            faderIndex++;
            if (faderIndex >= faders.length) faderIndex = 0;
            $(faders[faderIndex]).fadeIn(faderOutSpeed, nextFade);
        });
    }
    nextFade();
});
```

**HTML5 Range Input Method ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/75yKs/2/))**

First we'll make the range input in your HTML with a default value and range limitations.

```
<input id="range" type="range" value="2000" min="200" max="4000" step="200" />
<div id="fadey1" class="fadey"></div>
<div id="fadey2" class="fadey"></div>
```

Next, we'll bind a change handler on the range input to change the `faderSpeed` variable which is used as the speed in the fade animations. If you wanted a different value for the `fadeOut` speed, you could either do some computation or add a second range input.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var faderIndex = 0,
        faderSpeed = getRangeValue(),
        faders = $('.fadey');

    $('input#range').change(function () {
        faderSpeed = getRangeValue();
    });

    function getRangeValue() {
        return parseInt($('input#range').val(), 10);
    }

    function nextFade() {
        $(faders[faderIndex]).fadeOut(faderSpeed, function () {
            faderIndex++;
            if (faderIndex >= faders.length) faderIndex = 0;
            $(faders[faderIndex]).fadeIn(faderSpeed, nextFade);
        });
    }
    nextFade();
});
```

Comment: thank you @Ruben infante yes your code works fine , i am trying to do this using range button .

Comment: @user2024102 Do you mean the HTML5 element `<input type="range" />`?

Comment: @user2024102 I updated my answer with a second method using a range input.

Comment: Infanate Wow.. you are really cool . can i add repeat a single div alone for N number of times using user input

Comment: @user2024102 See if you can use what I have provided so far and try out a few things to see how far you get. If you still have trouble, you may want to create a new question and try to be specific about what you tried and exactly what result you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear too much, But you want the div will fadeout having an index

Like :

**SCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var faderIndex = 1,
    faders = $('.fadey');
    function nextFade(faderIndex) {
        $(faders).eq(faderIndex).fadeOut(2000, function() {
            faderIndex++;
            if (faderIndex >= faders.length)
                faderIndex = 0;
            $(faders).eq(faderIndex).fadeIn(3000, nextFade);
        });
    }
    nextFade(faderIndex);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="fadey">fadey 1</div>
<div class="fadey">fadey dfdsfd sdsf sdfds f</div>
```

Here is live demo http://jsfiddle.net/Ntk6a/