# Fade in and out text and repeat

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to adapt the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771088/fade-in-fade-out-using-dynamic-range-input-speed-and-repeat), however I can't get it to work like I would like it to.

I have some text in a `<p>` and I would like to have this text replaced with some other text and then repeat.

E.g. `text1` >  > `text2` >  > `text1`>...

I don't need any button or slider, just the fade-in, fade-out.

Thanks in advance!

---

My code:

HTML

```
<div class="fadey">Hallo</div>
<div class="fadey">Bonjour</div>
```

CSS

```
.myFade {
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var faderIndex = 0,
        faderOutSpeed = 2000,
        faderInSpeed = 3000,
        faders = $('.fadey');

    function nextFade() {
        $(faders[faderIndex]).fadeOut(1000, function () {
            faderIndex++;
            if (faderIndex >= faders.length) faderIndex = 0;
            $(faders[faderIndex]).fadeIn(1000, nextFade);
        });
    }
    nextFade();
});
```

How can I add a delay that let's the text stay a little longer visible before vanishing?

Comment: What issue are you having adapting the code?

Comment: you want to cycle through a fixed set of texts? Are the texts of equal length?

Comment: @guest271314 I don't really have experience with js, so even switching from button/slider to fixed value is complicated :/

Comment: @le_m Yes, approximately, but not exactly. I intend to rotate between different languages, so the texts won't have the same length.

Comment: share your code

Comment: @SanchitPatiyal http://jsfiddle.net/KYaAj/1/